# While running ruby and capybara code in irb, facing this issue : visit "http://google.co.uk"

Tags: ruby, capybara

TypeError: can't dup NilClass
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_capabilities.rb:101:in `dup'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_capabilities.rb:101:in`json_create'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:116:in `create_session'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:76:in`initialize'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:45:in `initialize'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in`new'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.3.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:87:in`for'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:13:in `browser'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:45:in`visit'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/session.rb:227:in `visit'
    from /scratch/rvm_details/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/capybara-2.4.4/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in`block (2 levels) in '
    from (irb):13
    from /scratch/rvm_details/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/irb:11:in `'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure to format your question correctly. Also, without your code that is throwing the error, you will most likely not getting any help at all. The title is also not clear (what does the "visit google" mean?). Your question will most likely be closed this way. Maybe have a look at how high-ranked questions are formatted and written in order to get a grasp about things are working on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Time to upgrade - Ruby 2.1.x and selenium-webdriver 3.3.x are massively out of date.